# Split multiple names separated by semicolon into separate cells - Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a series which goes something like this

`John Blogs;John Bloggs;Jean Bloke;Jordon Bean`, etc etc up to 10 names in a cell.

I need a formula to split each full name into a separate cell...I've been working with `MID`, `FIND`, etc but can't seem to get past the 3 name before coming unstuck!!!

Wonder if anyone can help!

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Does Excel have Split() method? VB has it

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using "text-to-column" function with semi-colon as a delimiter.

If you insist on using formula, this will work for you:

1. Let's assume you text is in cell `A1`. Then in B1 type `=";"&A1&";"`.
2. Input 1 to 9 from cell `A2` to `I2`.
3. In `A3`, type in the formula `=MID($B$1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,";",CHAR(1),A2))+1,FIND(CHAR(2),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,";",CHAR(2),A2+1))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,";",CHAR(1),A2))-1)`.
4. Copy this formula to `B3`, `C3`, .. , `I3`.

Comment: I can confirm that. Using "text-to-column" is the easiest way as a one-time-solution. Check this how-to: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

Split your work over many columns rather than a single formula.

You are correct to use `FIND()` to get the offset of the ";".

And to use `LEFT()` to extract a name, with `MID()` to extract the remaining string.

Then you either have an empty cell, or you have a cell with up to 9 names in it.

Repeat the process across the sheet to get all your names, plus perhaps some cells containing `#VALUE` errors.

---

To display the output without the errors, use something like `=IF(ISERR( A1 ), "", A1)`.

Of course hide all your working once done.